# Can the value of a variable be made to persist between front end sessions?

Tags: programming, variable-definitions

For example, say I create a notebook with a cell

```
a = 5 + 2
```

and then I close *Mathematica*, reopen the notebook, enter a new cell

```
b = a*2
```

and evaluate the new cell with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. I want the output to be 14 without evaluating to evaluate the first cell. Is this posible?

---

I want this because i'm making a Stylesheet Creator and i have ColorSelectors, inputfield, etc and i want to have dafault values.

Comment: @Jens but that is for execute and evaluate an external notebook... i want a way to open manually a notebook and autoevaluate cells in the same notebook

EDIT: my bad yes it's duplicated u.u

Comment: Notwithstanding that you say the link answers your question, the framing of the question actually suggests that you need variables localized in the notebook. I'd suggest you read the docs on `TaggingRules`. IMO it would be easier to do what you want that way.